The Omniscient Vegetable
You've just broken into your half-sister's boyfriend's mother's secret stash. It is full of all sorts of magical devices, including a strange vegetative organism. According to some notes your friend found, it reacts to questions, either shuddering or blooming when it is asked any yes/no question. However, the notes warn that its behaviour changes cyclically with each question, with three states:

blooming, where it blooms for yes and  shudders for no
shuddering, where it shudders for yes and blooms for no
random, where its blooms and shudders randomly

It will not answer at all, no matter the state, if the question is not yes/no or is impossible to answer with certainty. If it doesn't answer it doesn't move onto the next state in the cycle
The notes offer no insight into the length or arrangement of the cycle, but your half-sister's boyfriend claims it can't be longer than ten states. You can also assume all three states are present in the cycle
Your initial testing indicates that it won't answer to tautologies or definite facts, but instead only answers questions that you don't already know the answer to. This includes questions about itself
Given this, what is the minimum amount of questions required to work out the vegetable's cycle?

can you ask about its past or future answers as yes/no or only as bloom/shudder? Can you ask about the states by name?

Do you just need to know the length of the cycle, or what state it is in at each step?

also does "impossible to answer with certainty" refer to not knowing, or to a paradox? Since it tells the truth (just with different gestures) it cannot answer "will you answer no to this question" and if it's in a bloom-means-no state it cannot answer "will you bloom in response to this question" so will it just not answer and not use up a step in the cycle, as it would if it was in random state?

also "it can't be longer than ten states" - states? or steps? Eg is BRRS three states long, or four steps long? What about BBBBBBBBBBRRRRRRRRRSSSSSSS - three states? or more than ten steps?

With regards to "questions that you don't already know the answer to" will it answer a question that you don't immediately know, but would know if you stopped and thought about things a bit? For example , if you ask "Is 673423777 prime?" will it answer if you know that any number >3 with digital sum = 3 cannot be prime, but haven't bothered to check if that is the case for that specific number.

Is tag [[tag:mathematics]] applicable?

It cannot change into the same state? Or can it?

The questions are really restrictive. You can't ask about anything in the past, because you know the answer. You can't even ask current stuff you're sure of like "am I holding up one finger" or "is today Tuesday". I think the questions you can ask are these:

 Will you bloom in response to this question?
 Will you shudder in response to this question?
 After answering this question, will you be in Random state?

(For the last one, but not the first two, you can substitute another state name.)
You start by asking the first question. If the plant is Blooming,

 it will bloom, meaning yes

And you can write down a B.
If it is Shuddering,

 it will be unable to answer due to the paradox.

If it is Random,

 it won't know how it will answer until it answers, so it can't answer.

If the plant bloomed, continue to ask the same question until it can't answer. Record a B each time.
Once it has reached a state it can't answer, ask the second question. A Blooming plant

 can't answer "Will you shudder" because of the paradox.

A Shuddering plant

 will shudder and you can record an S

A Random plant

 can't answer

If it shudders, ask the same question again until it can't answer.
Some times you know it is random. If you ask the first question and get no answer, then immediately (so it's still in the same state) ask the second question and get no answer

 You know it is neither B nor S so must be random. Record an R.

The same applies if you ask the second and get no answer, then immediately ask the first and get no answer.
If you don't know for sure it is random, ask the first question again, and repeat as before.

 However a random cannot answer either the first or second question, and won't move on, so you could ask those two questions forever without progress.

When it is random what you need to do is get it moving to the next step. The answer it gives is not important. So you ask the third question and ignore the answer. Then you go back to the first question.
When you look at the pattern of B, R, and S you have recorded, you should see the cycle before it gets to a length of 10. I don't know how many questions that requires because you will ask more than 10 questions to get a sequence of 10 known steps.
Let me test it with the one of the sequences suggested in the other answer: BRSRRR. The notation will be that 1? means asking the first question, b, s, or - are the plant response, and B, R, or S are the state I record.

 BRSRRR goes 1?bB1?-2?-R3?x1?-2?sS2?-1?-R3?x1?-2?-R3?x1?-2?-R3?x1?bB1?-2?-R3?x1?-2?sS2?-1?-R  that's 10 states and it did repeat after 6. It took 23 questions.


I think there is a small problem with you logic. The puzzle states that "its behaviour changes cyclically with each question", so your instruction "If you ask the first question and get no answer, then immediately (so it's still in the same state)..." won't work as it changes state after each question, not after providing an answer.

@Penguino It will not answer at all, no matter the state, if the question is not yes/no or is impossible to answer with certainty. If it doesn't answer it doesn't move onto the next state in the cycle

I'm not sure if it's possible to guarantee in any finite number of questions.

 Suppose you were told that it has one of two cycles:
 Length 6, blooming on one, shuddering on three, random other steps
 Length 8, blooming on two, shuddering on four, random on other steps
 Also, flowers in the random state, if the other cycle would have a blooming or shuddering phase for that question, would give the same result as if it were in the other cycle.
 For example, if you repeatedly asked "Is the length of the cycle 6?" you would get results:
 BsSb__B_ Ss_bB_S_ sBbS__ BsSb__B_ Ss_bB_S_ sBbS__
 (Capital letters are where the six-cycle forces it; lowercase letters are where the eight-cycle forces it; underscores mean it's random either way.)
 I don't think it's possible to distinguish these cases.  Perhaps you need "It's in the random state less than half the time" or "The cycle is of prime length."


I think those cycles can be differentiated with a question like "if the next question i ask is X, will you bloom?" If the next state is random the veggi won't be able to answer which eventually will let you map out where the random states are.

I can do it in 19 questions.
My first question is:

 Is it the case that either the cycle has 7 or more states or the
 answer to this question is 'no'?

 Note that this structure allows us to get a yes/no answer regardless
 of the current state - it will either bloom or shudder if the answer
 to the first clause is 'yes', but if it's 'no' then the whole question
 becomes a paradox so it will do nothing.
 We know that it has
 between 3 and 10 states, so with 8 possibilities it will take 3 yes/no
 questions to find the exact length.

Once we have know the cycle length, we need to figure out the state at each step:

 Following our template as above, we can ask two questions to find
 the state of each step:
  Is it the case that either the first step
 of the cycle has a blooming state or the answer to this question is
 'no'?
  Is it the case that either the first step of the cycle has a
 shuddering state or the answer to this question is 'no'?
 If neither question gets an answer then the first step must be
 shuddering.
 Repeat for all steps (up to 10).  This gives us a
 worst case of 3 + 2 * 10 = 23 questions.

But we can optimize a bit from here:

 Notice that in our worst case of 10 steps, we got 'yes' answers to
 our first 3 questions.  If it bloomed on 'yes' for the first question,
 then the state of the first step can't be shuddering, so we only need
 one question to determine if it's random or blooming.
 Saving 1 question on each of the first 3 states brings us down to 20 questions.

And one more optimization:

 If we get a 'yes' answer to our first question about a step in the
 cycle, then we don't need to ask the second one.  So, we want to guess
 the most common state first.  We ask 2 questions:
  Is it the case
 that either blooming is the most (or tied for most) common state in
 steps 4-10 of the cycle or the answer to this question is 'no'?
  Is it the case that either shuddering is the most (or tied for most)
 common state in steps 4-10 of the cycle or the answer to this question
 is 'no'?
 With 7 steps that we know nothing about, the most common
 state must occur at least 3 times.

So, we have:

 3 questions - to establish the cycle length
 3 questions - 1 each
 for the first 3 cycles (with a cycle shorter than 10 steps, we'll
 have fewer partially-known steps, but no more fully-unknown steps, so
 we still do better overall)
 2 questions - to find the
 most-common state for the remaining steps
 3 questions - for
 whichever 3 remaining steps are in the most common state
 8 questions - for the 4 remaining steps that we need 2 questions each
 for

19 questions total

Optimal number of questions is

 11

There are three states. Each question changes the state (if it is not a paradox), and eventually they repeat after at most 10 states.
We need to find the exact sequence of states. (Find the cycle.)
This means we are looking for...

 A base three number less than 3^10, where two consecutive digits cannot be the same.

 Digits 0,1,2 represent states. We consider each valid ternary number with and without a leading zero digit (if the unit digit is not already zero), to represent all possible cycles as sequences of digits.

 There are only 2046 possible such sequences of digits.

 But since the cycle is cyclic, we could further remove the duplicates. For example, cycle '012' is the same as cycle '012012'. This brings the number of possible cycles to 1968.


We can use the following question structure (thanks to @sadvak's answer):

 Question: "Is it the case that [?] or the answer to this question is 'no'?"

 It will bloom or shudder if [?] is true, otherwise it won't answer due to a paradox.

 This allows us to get a "yes/no" information regardless of the state.

To find our cycle, we can do as follows:

 We enumerate (index) each cycle sequence.

 We then use our question structure to preform the binary search.

 That is, we ask our question and [?] will be "Cycle index is inside [a, b] interval."

 That is, we can eliminate half of the possibilities with each question.

 This means we will at worst, have to ask floor(log2(n)+1) questions.

 This turns out to be 11.

This cannot be improved because:

 As the question currently stands, it seems most information one can extract from a single question is one bit of information (yes or no to some clause, i.e. paradox or no paradox).

 Observing the blooming and shuddering while doing binary search, won't provide any extra information in the worst case. That is, at worst it will never change states if the main question is a paradox every time.


I assumed that by "change the state", OP means "change into a different state". If this is not the case, the answer is the same except that the number of questions would increase.

It's possible to get more than 1 bit - for example, plug "the current state is non-random" into the question template to get the exact current state in one question.  I don't know if that'd be enough to get down to 10 questions, though.

Assuming "change the state" does allow a 'change' to the same state, and using the pattern sadvak established in his answer:

 16 questions is enough.

Phase 1:

 Q1 Is it the case that either the cycle has 10 states or the answer to this question is 'no'?
 Q2 Is it the case that either the cycle has 9 or more states or the answer to this question is 'no'?
 Q3 Is it the case that either the cycle has 8 or more states or the answer to this question is 'no'?
 etc...

 N questions to establish that the cycle lenght is 11-N
 and that the first state is either:
 - blooming or random on a blooming reaction
 - shuddering or random on a shuddering reaction

 Each time there is no reaction the maximum cycle lenght decreases 1 and thus the possibilities decrease with a factor 3.
  Worst case would be an immediate reaction this leaves 2*3^9 = 39,366 possibilities.

Phase 2:

 Q2: Is it the case that either (neither the 9th nor 10th state is random) or the answer to this question is 'no'?
 No reaction on Q2: 4/9th of the possibilities remaining.
 then Q3: Is it the case that either (neither the 7th nor 8th state is random) or the answer to this question is 'no'?
 - No reaction: 7,776 possibilities left (go to stage 3)
 - Some reaction on Q3:   Q4: Is it the case that either the current state is not random or the answer to this question is 'no'? (see below)

 Some reaction on Q2:  5/9th of the possibilities remaining.
 Q3: Is it the case that either the current state is not random or the answer to this question is 'no'?
 - random: paradox-> no reaction
 - blooming state: yes->blooming reaction
 - shuddering: yes->shuddering reaction
 7,290 possibilities(5/27th) left (go to stage 3)

Phase 3:

 Ask binary questions, splitting the remaining possibilities in half each time.

 So, by tacking worst case first (long cycle length), and then using that we can sometimes discern 3 different outcomes, and trigger those by asking slightly unbalanced questions that steer into such a situation:
 Total questions needed: 16

